# Ansible - When statement using the variable

Tags: python, json, linux, ansible

I have a Ansible playbook which is used to check the availability of multiple web portals. Following is my playbook:

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Checking the Application availability status...
      uri:
        url: https://{{ item }}.example.com
      with_inventory_hostnames:
        - production
      ignore_errors: yes
      register: uptime
```

Following is the output of the above task:

```
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "uptime": {
        "changed": false, 
        "msg": "All items completed", 
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": true, 
                "_ansible_item_label": "server1", 
                "_ansible_item_result": true, 
                "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                "_ansible_parsed": true, 
                "cache_control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate", 
                "changed": false, 
                "connection": "close", 
                "content_type": "text/html;charset=UTF-8", 
                "cookies": {
                    "JSESSIONID": "A9058dfgD19850855C02B4"
                }, 
                "cookies_string": "JSESSIONID=A9058343534fghjuy50855C02B4", 
                "date": "Fri, 05 Apr 2019 11:03:18 GMT", 
                "expires": "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT", 
                "failed": false, 
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "attributes": null, 
                        "backup": null, 
                        "body": null, 
                        "body_format": "raw", 
                        "client_cert": null, 
                        "client_key": null, 
                        "content": null, 
                        "creates": null, 
                        "delimiter": null, 
                        "dest": null, 
                        "directory_mode": null, 
                        "follow": false, 
                        "follow_redirects": "safe", 
                        "force": false, 
                        "force_basic_auth": false, 
                        "group": null, 
                        "headers": {}, 
                        "http_agent": "ansible-httpget", 
                        "method": "GET", 
                        "mode": null, 
                        "owner": null, 
                        "regexp": null, 
                        "remote_src": null, 
                        "removes": null, 
                        "return_content": false, 
                        "selevel": null, 
                        "serole": null, 
                        "setype": null, 
                        "seuser": null, 
                        "src": null, 
                        "status_code": [
                            200
                        ], 
                        "timeout": 30, 
                        "unsafe_writes": null, 
                        "url": "https://myapp.com/Login.xhtml", 
                        "url_password": null, 
                        "url_username": null, 
                        "use_proxy": true, 
                        "validate_certs": true
                    }
                }, 
                "item": "server1", 
                "msg": "OK (unknown bytes)", 
                "pragma": "no-cache", 
                "redirected": false, 
                "server": "nginx", 
                "set_cookie": "JSESSIONID=A90583ggggh9850855C02B4; Expires=Fri, 05-Apr-2019 23:03:18 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly", 
                "status": 200, 
                "strict_transport_security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;", 
                "transfer_encoding": "chunked", 
                "url": "https://myapp.com/Login.xhtml", 
                "vary": "Accept-Encoding", 
                "x_frame_options": ""
            }, 
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": true, 
                "_ansible_item_label": "server2", 
                "_ansible_item_result": true, 
                "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                "_ansible_parsed": true, 
                "cache_control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate", 
                "changed": false, 
                "connection": "close", 
                "content_type": "text/html;charset=UTF-8", 
                "cookies": {
                    "JSESSIONID": "647948952hgftrfEC51119"
                }, 
                "cookies_string": "JSESSIONID=64794cccvf52C4EC51119", 
                "date": "Fri, 05 Apr 2019 11:03:20 GMT", 
                "expires": "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT", 
                "failed": false, 
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "attributes": null, 
                        "backup": null, 
                        "body": null, 
                        "body_format": "raw", 
                        "client_cert": null, 
                        "client_key": null, 
                        "content": null, 
                        "creates": null, 
                        "delimiter": null, 
                        "dest": null, 
                        "directory_mode": null, 
                        "follow": false, 
                        "follow_redirects": "safe", 
                        "force": false, 
                        "force_basic_auth": false, 
                        "group": null, 
                        "headers": {}, 
                        "http_agent": "ansible-httpget", 
                        "method": "GET", 
                        "mode": null, 
                        "owner": null, 
                        "regexp": null, 
                        "remote_src": null, 
                        "removes": null, 
                        "return_content": false, 
                        "selevel": null, 
                        "serole": null, 
                        "setype": null, 
                        "seuser": null, 
                        "src": null, 
                        "status_code": [
                            200
                        ], 
                        "timeout": 30, 
                        "unsafe_writes": null, 
                        "url": "https://myapp.com/Login.xhtml", 
                        "url_password": null, 
                        "url_username": null, 
                        "use_proxy": true, 
                        "validate_certs": true
                    }
                }, 
                "item": "server2", 
                "msg": "OK (unknown bytes)", 
                "pragma": "no-cache", 
                "redirected": false, 
                "server": "nginx", 
                "set_cookie": "JSESSIONID=647948952cccc1119; Expires=Fri, 05-Apr-2019 23:03:20 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly", 
                "status": 200, 
                "strict_transport_security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;", 
                "transfer_encoding": "chunked", 
                "url": "://myapp.com/Login.xhtml", 
                "vary": "Accept-Encoding", 
                "x_frame_options": ""
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have created another task which will extract the status code from the registered variable:

```
- name: Setting up the status code fact...
  set_fact: 
     api_status: "{{ uptime | json_query('[results[*].status]') }}"`

I'm receiving the expected output as below when I `debug`:

`ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            200, 
            200
        ]
    ]
}
```

Now, I'm trying to set up an email task which will notify me if the response code is other than `200`:

```
- name: Notifying the IT team about the outage...
   mail:
    host: smtp.server.com
    port: 25
    username: my@example.com
    password: mypassword
    subtype: html
    from: noreply@company.com
    to: admin@company.com
    subject: Server Outage
    body: Hi {{ uptime | json_query('results[*].item') }} is down
   when: api_status !=200
```

But the `when` statement never works. I always receive the email notification regardless of the status code. What might be the issue?

Comment: `api_status` is a list, so of course `api_status != 200` will always be `true`, because a list will never equal an integer.

Comment: @larsks thanks. I'm not a advanced ansible user and my programming knowledge is limited. Could you please help me to solve the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is probably to get rid of your `json_query` bits and instead just loop over the results of your `uri` task, and generate email when the status of the corresponding item is not 200.

You'll want to read through the Ansible documentation on [using `register` in a loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#using-register-with-a-loop) to understand what's going on.

You would use something like this:

```
- name: Notifying the IT team about the outage...
  mail:
    host: smtp.server.com
    port: 25
    username: my@example.com
    password: mypassword
    subtype: html
    from: noreply@company.com
    to: admin@company.com
    subject: "Server Outage {{ item.item }}"
    body: "{{ item.item }} is down"
  when: item.status != 200
  loop: "{{ uptime.results }}"
```

This iterates over `uptime.results`, which contains the result of each `uri` task that you execute in your initial loop.  Within each iteration of this task, `item` is a result of a `uri` task, and `item.item` is the corresponding hostname that was the input into the `uri` task.